# Google My Maps: how to limit embedding?

Tags: google-maps

I created a map using Google My Maps, and now I want to embed it in my website, but I want to control who else can embed it. How can I do so?

I have been reading up on the documentation, and haven't found any way. Perhaps the only way is to sign up for Google's Developer API and use the embed API?